# Fabric.js performance issues or sharing objects

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, maps, fabricjs

I am working on some kind of seating plan application which looks like this
[image]
[image]

Generally speaking everything is working, but there are some performance issues with such big plans (which can include up to 3000 seats which can translate to around 3000 `Group` objects and 12-15k objects (4-5 per group - seat).

I was wondering if there are any tricks that could be used here to improve the performance since a lot of these "seats" look very similar (like 1000 can be of the same color). So I was thinking if some optimization could be done here to for example have some shared cache for these - so all 1000 objects would share same cached object for rendering. Or if there are maybe other things that could be done here.

The biggest problem here seem to be the zooming (very clunky) and moving/panning. Interesingly with bigger zoom the app works better which for me is weird since I would guess that the total canvas dimensions in that scenario will be bigger.
The other problem is definitely the memory consumption which as we found out is so big on Safari that it crashes the browser making the app totally unusable.

Do you guys have any advices what could I look at to maybe make it more responsive and less memory hungry ? I was playing around with pixi.js where there is a concept of textures and with approach of making 1 texture per seat color and re-using these textures the app worked in almost 60fps, the con was unfortunately that it looked blurry and texts were looking badly, but I guess that would be something that could be worked out. What do you think ? Or maybe I should take a look at some other library for such case (recently I was thinking about Leaflet JS) ?

Comment: Nothing that can be done if you are using 3rd party rendering (fabricjs). The canvas API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D is much faster if you use it directly.

Comment: Well, I don't believe so :) Especially considering that PixiJS is also a library and is able to provide nearly perfect performance. Of course native will be faster, but would require creating "own" framework on top of the canvas anyway making it hard to maintain later. Also I think there could be some libraries/solutions already capable of handling such thing so I was thinking that maybe someone could share some opinion on other approaches like Leaflet/Conva/something I don't know yet :)

Comment: PixiJS uses the webGL API to render (which is much quicker than 2D canvas API). No matter how you frame the problem you are forced to add a layer of abstraction (seating) on top of the rendering API, why compound the overhead by adding a JS framework to already excellent native framework?

Comment: @Maksym did you ever figure out a path forward here? I'm facing a similar use case and problem as you. I've looked into Leaflet as well and the problem there has to do with the limited ability to place text within a container. It can be achieved with custom SVG 'markers' in leaflet but then pan/zoom performance suffers as many SVGs are placed onto the map.

Comment: Nothing spectacularfor now. From what I discussed with fabric.js team they are working on a couple features which would allow to better caching and possibly allow to cache certain objects for re-use. But this is going to come up in fabric 6 or maybe even later. So we have to live with it for now. Of course @Blindman67 is somewhat right that possibly writing all of this in pure Canvas API would be faster, but not so sure about the potential gains and very sure about potential issues with further maintenance of this solution (let's be honest, Fabric is documented very well :))